# Getting certificate error in Uploading image with https Amazon AWS

Tags: objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, image-uploading

I am facing an issue while uploading image in Amazon AWS. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

protocol ContentUploaderDelegate {

    func onContentLoadComplete(status:Bool,serverResponse:String)
}


class ContentUploader
{
    let contentURL = "https:<MY URL>amazonaws.com/api/v1/contents"
    var delegate:ContentUploaderDelegate?


    func uploadImage(image:UIImage,xAuth:String,mimeType:String,imageName:String)
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: contentURL)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        //define the multipart request type
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue(xAuth, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-auth-token")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")

        let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)

        if(image_data == nil)
        {
            return
        }

        let body = NSMutableData()

        //name to save in server
        let fname = imageName
        let mimetype = mimeType

        //define the data post parameter
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("hi\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(image_data!)
        body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        //set the HTTPBody
        request.HTTPBody = body

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (
            let data, let response, let error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
                print("error")
                self.delegate?.onContentLoadComplete(false, serverResponse: (error?.description)!)
                return
            }

            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("success \(dataString)")
            self.delegate?.onContentLoadComplete(true, serverResponse:dataString! as String)
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    private func generateBoundaryString() -> String
    {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    }
```

**The following delegate method never gets called. What could be the reason?**

```
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                    task: NSURLSessionTask,
                    didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
                                        completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?)
        -> Void) {

        let protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace

        let theSender = challenge.sender

        if protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
            if (challenge.protectionSpace.host == "ec2-52-36-216-81.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com") {
                if let theTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust{

                    let theCredential = NSURLCredential(trust: theTrust)

                    theSender!.useCredential(theCredential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

                    return
                }
            }
        }
        theSender!.performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge!(challenge)

        return
    }
}
```

**And I am getting the following error. Any idea why getting this error?**

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this
>   server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is
>   pretending to be “.amazonaws.com” which could put your
>   confidential information at risk."
>   UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to
>   connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : .com i: www..com> )}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d42aedc10 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : .com i: www..com> )}}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is
>   invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information
>   at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://amazonaws.com/api/v1/contents,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://.amazonaws.com/api/v1/contents,
>   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “.amazonaws.com”
```

I believe something is wrong with the common name *“.amazonaws.com”*

```
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://amazonaws.com/api/v1/contents,
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://.amazonaws.com/api/v1/contents
```

The URLs shown in the error message do not appear to be a well know endpoint.  I would expect to see something like `https://ec2-2-2-2-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com`  or another Fully Qualified Domain name there.

The error message also confirms this.  You are connecting a host, but the name on the certificate does not match. This is the reason for the  `pretending to be “.amazonaws.com”` error.

Confirm the correct endpoint, and how your code is forming the full URL.

> The following delegate method never gets called. What could be the
>   reason?

The error occurs before the function is called. The session is never established because of the certificate error.

Comment: The URL is something like https://ec2-2-2-2-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com only.

Comment: Yes, it should be, but your code is not producing a valid URL. Hence the error.

Comment: Look at the NSErrorFailingURLStringKey value in the error message. It is not a valid URL